# What to run a script during startup or shutdown so that the group priveleges becomes effective

Tags: batch-file, window

I am trying to give "Impersonate a client after authentication" to a user based on the registry. Since the registry can be changed by user at anytime. So during the next restart the privelege shud be effective. To achieve the same im trying to run a script at startup which checks fr the registry, if that registry is set then that particular privilege is assigned.
But looks like my script is nt being executed

Answer (score 1):

How did you invoke the script?
Did you add them to windows startup folder?
Or used GPO's?

The best way to do this is to use group policies.

use gpedit to do the same

Under Local group policy-

Go to computer configuration ->windows setting-> scripts